# Array returns empty data

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-2013, vba

I have this very odd situation. The code works in a previous sub, but in another sub it does nothing. I dug deeper and found out that the array seems to be empty. How is this possible:

```
Sub Knop1_Klikken()
Dim cbm_cnt, cbm_xnt, cbm_c, cbm_r As Integer
cbm_xnt = 1
cbm_cnt = 0
cbm_r = 1
cbm_c = 1
Dim cbm_Arr() As Variant ' declare an unallocated array.
Worksheets("Cbm").Activate

cbm_lrow = Worksheets("totallist").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
cbm_lcol = Worksheets("totallist").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

cbm_Arr = Range(Sheets("totallist").Cells(1, 1).Address, Sheets("totallist").Cells(cbm_lrow, cbm_lcol).Address)

For cbm_r = 1 To UBound(cbm_Arr, 1) ' First array dimension is rows.
    For cbm_c = 1 To UBound(cbm_Arr, 2) ' Second array dimension is columns.
        If Worksheets("totallist").Cells(cbm_r, 9).Value = "Cbm" Then
            cbm_cnt = cbm_cnt + 1
            If cbm_cnt = 10 Then
                 cbm_xnt = cbm_xnt + 1
                 cbm_cnt = 1
            End If
            Worksheets("Cbm").Cells(cbm_xnt, cbm_cnt).Value = cbm_Arr(cbm_r, cbm_c)
            Worksheets("Cbm").Cells(cbm_xnt, 7).Value = ""
        End If

    Next cbm_c
Next cbm_r
End Sub
```

In the code `cbm_Arr(cbm_r, cbm_c)` seems to be empty.

What does the code suppose to do:
In a sheet called "*totallist*" I am looking in a column-I for a the code cbm. If this code is found then it copies the row in another sheet called "*cbm*". What am I doing wrong?

Add: When I do this

```
Worksheets("Cbm").Cells(cbm_xnt, cbm_cnt).Value = "x"
```

Then I column gets the "x" in the cells. The array does not show...

NB: cbm_lrow = 511 and cbm_lcol= 9

Comment: What are the values of `cbm_lrow` and `cbm_lcol` while debugging?

Comment: cbm_lrow = 511 and cbm_lcol= 9

Answer (score 2):

The `Range` function you are using applies to the active sheet, not your `totallist` sheet. You need to use the full sheet name:

```
With Sheets("totallist")
    cbm_arr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1).Address, .Cells(cbm_lrow, cbm_lcol).Address).Value
End With
```

or

```
cbm_Arr = Sheets("totallist").Range(Sheets("totallist").Cells(1, 1).Address, Sheets("totallist").Cells(cbm_lrow, cbm_lcol).Address).Value
```